# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**showing this**

Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `visible`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: visible="false" or visible={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with visible={condition && value}, pass visible={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
**please please.. put your suggestion or explain me about my mistakes on this code.**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {
  CAvatar,
  CBadge,
  CDropdown,
  CImg,
  CDropdownItem,
  CDropdownMenu,
  CDropdownToggle,
  CModalTitle,
  CModalHeader,
  CModalFooter,
  CButton,
  CModal,
  CModalBody
} from '@coreui/react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const TheHeaderDropdown = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const logOut = (e) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("hrms_auth");
    history.push("/login")
  }

  return (
    <CDropdown
      inNav
      className="c-header-nav-items mx-2"
      direction="down"
    >
      <CDropdownToggle className="c-header-nav-link" caret={false}>
        <div className="c-avatar">
          <CImg
            src={'avatars/6.jpg'}
            className="c-avatar-img"
            alt="admin@bootstrapmaster.com"
          />
        </div>
      </CDropdownToggle>
      <CDropdownMenu className="pt-0" placement="bottom-end">
        <CDropdownItem
          header
          tag="div"
          color="light"
          className="text-center"
        >
          <strong>Account</strong>
        </CDropdownItem>
        <CDropdownItem>
          <CIcon name="cil-bell" className="mfe-2" />
          Updates
          <CBadge color="info" className="mfs-auto">42</CBadge>
        </CDropdownItem>
        <CDropdownItem
          header
          tag="div"
          color="light"
          className="text-center"
        >
          <strong>Settings</strong>
        </CDropdownItem>
        <CDropdownItem>
          <CIcon name="cil-user" className="mfe-2" />Profile
        </CDropdownItem>
        <CDropdownItem divider />

        <CDropdownItem onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}><CIcon name="cil-lock-locked" className="mfe-2" />Logout</CDropdownItem>

        <CModal visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)}> 
          <CModalHeader onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
            <CModalTitle>Logout</CModalTitle>
          </CModalHeader>
          <CModalBody>Are You Sure You Want To Continue ?</CModalBody>
          <CModalFooter>
            <CButton color="secondary" onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
              Close
            </CButton>
            <CButton color="primary" onClick={logOut}>Continue</CButton>
          </CModalFooter>
        </CModal> 
      </CDropdownMenu>
    </CDropdown>
  )
}

export default TheHeaderDropdown
```

Comment: What does `CModal` expect in its `visible` property?

Comment: What version of coreui library you using?

Comment: 3.2.1 @DhavalGajjar

Answer (score 3):

You are using coreui version 3.x and the code seems to be used from version 4.x. So in the 3.x version CModal doesn't have `visible` property instead it has a `show` property.

Check out the documentation https://coreui.io/react/docs/3.3/components/CModal.